# Keep track of everybody who uses my code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tumblr

I made a theme for tumblr and I want to release the code to the public. The thing is,  want to know how many people are using my theme. Is there any javascript or other solution to this other than google analytic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add to your code some javascript that sends a GET request to a php page that logs the request. You need to grab the tumblr `document.URL` when you do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
xmlHttp.open( "GET", '//mywebsite.com/tumblr_code_check.php?referrer='+document.URL, true );
xmlHttp.send( null );
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$referrer = $_GET['referrer'];
$file = '';
$filename = 'tumblr_refferalls.txt';
$file = file_get_contents ($filename); 
file_put_contents ($filename, $referrer."\n");
?>
```

Then check the file tumblr_refferalls.txt. You can add some code to the php page ignore your own website, to prevent it from filling up.

Please note that anyone can remove the javascript from your code.

You can get more detailed, such as adding a timestamp, filtering it so you only get the page URL once appended to your logfile, have it send you a text message or email when someone new uses your code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tracking pixel, a 1x1 image and just include it in the markup. Of course any end-user is free to remove it. I urge you to refrain from other methods, as you will not only raise red flags with anybody who looks into your theme, but you may negatively impact their PHP or JS execution should your host ever fail to connect.